# An iconic WW2 weapon. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> My families are noble, my moves are nimble.
>   
>   Look like a seagull, yet I don't live at seashore.
>   
>   I will freak you out, if you hear me shout!

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only figured out two of the clues, but that was enough:

> Look like a seagull, yet I don't live at seashore.

> Refers to a [gull wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gull_wing)

> I will freak you out, if you hear me shout!

> Refers to a siren

One thing that has both:

> The [Junkers Ju 87](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Ju_87), a German dive bomber with a [distinctive siren](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZZ504TGDpE).

Comment: You've got it! For the first line, you can think about its company name.